# What is the best way to store a password in Java swing?

Tags: java, encryption, hash, passwords

I am trying to make my own password manager and I want to store the passwords I input with some encryption/hashing algorithm. I researched on what would be the best and everyone seems to have mixed opinions on it. Would it be best to save them in a database or locally in the program? And what is the best hashing algorithm for passwords? I saw that there are things like BCrypt and SCrypt but I couldn't get a definitive answer on what is best.

Comment: Swing is not relevant to this question.  The question is about storing passwords and Swing is not a technology for storing things.

Answer (score 2):

> I researched on what would be the best and everyone seems to have mixed opinions on it.

Obviously!  (See below)

> Would it be best to save them in a database or locally in the program?

The point of using seeded hashes is to make it difficult for the attacker if they have managed to get hold of the data.  They now have to use a "brute force" approach to find clear text passwords that match the passwords.  Properly implemented seeding means that this must be done for each individual hash, rather than in bulk; e.g. using so-called "rainbow tables".

But the fact remains that if the attacker is able to steal the hashes and the seeds, they can probably crack any weak passwords.

So "local" versus "database" actually depends on which of those provides more secure storage.  That is not something we can answer.  It depends on how secure the two options are in >>your<< system, which depends on how you implement them, and how well you (or someone else) secures the systems on which they run.

> And what is the best hashing algorithm for passwords?

Any crypto hashing algorithm that is currently considered secure will do.  The "best" is a matter of opinion.

> I saw that there are things like BCrypt and SCrypt but I couldn't get a definitive answer on what is best.

Either of those will do.

The "best" is a matter of opinion.

The only way you would be able to get a **definitive** answer is if you could use a time machine, go 100 years or so into the future, then read the IT / security history books to see which hashing algorithms / implementations were cracked last.

My advice: if you can't decide, use a "binary numismatic decision making device"<sup>1</sup> to choose between the alternatives that seem to be the best ... according to your previous (hopefully extensive!) research.

Here are some links to aid your research:

- [About Secure Password Hashing](https://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/)
- [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html)
- [What password hash function for the next 50 years](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61059/what-password-hash-function-for-the-next-50-year)
- [Password Hashing Competition (PHC)](https://password-hashing.net/) which declared [Argon2](https://github.com/p-h-c/phc-winner-argon2) to be the winner.

Finally, you should consider what it is you are trying to protect with your passwords / password manager.  Is it important enough to justify lots of implementation effort?

---

<sup>1 - Toss a coin ...</sup>